# Display java script preload banner before html document loaded - Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to be able to show an advertisement banner using JavaScript while the page is loading (before other HTML elements are loaded).  I've tried the following, but it only loads a few seconds after the rest of the body content has loaded:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState != 'uninitialized') checkCookie();
}
```

How should I go about making the ad load before the other HTML elements?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

first you can set

```
body { display: none; }
```

and then call the preload function to load all the required images. like this

```
preload('image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg');
```

and at the end of function you can change style of body tag to make it visible again.

```
.visible { display: block; }

function preload(images) {
    if (document.images) {
        var i = 0;
        var imageArray = new Array();
        imageArray = images.split(',');
        var imageObj = new Image();
        for(i=0; i<=imageArray.length-1; i++) {
            //document.write('<img src="' + imageArray[i] + '" />');// Write to page (uncomment to check images)
            imageObj.src=imageArray[i];
        }

     // ------ add class to body tag to make it visible again
     var d = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
     d.className = d.className + " visible";
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can execute JavaScript is in a script tag before the document is parsed:

```
<head>
<script>

// your script here
alert(); //for example

</script>
</head>
```